# Showing existence of a solution for a system of equations involving expectations of random variables

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $f_k(x)$, $k \in \{0,\dots,M\}$, $ M\geq 2$, a set of distinct probability density functions in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\{\alpha_k\}_{k=1}^M$ a set of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^M \alpha_k =1$. Is it generally possible to find a choice of $\{\alpha_k\}_{k=1}^M$ such that

\begin{align}
\int  \left(\log \frac{\sum_{k=1}^M \alpha_m f_k(x)}{f_0(x)} \right) f_s(x) dx= \int \left(\log \frac{\sum_{k=1}^M \alpha_m f_k(x)}{f_0(x)} \right) f_j(x) dx
\end{align}
for all $s,j \in \{1,\dots,M\}$. I believe the result holds for the case that $M=2$ and for general distribution choices, however I am not sure for the case that $M>2$. Is there an example of pdfs such that such a choice of $\{\alpha_k\}_{k=1}^M$ can be found? It looks like we have to find a solution to a system of $M$ nonlinear equations. I am not sure how to proceed with showing that a solution exists.

Comment: It holds true whenever $f_0$ is a convex combination of $f_1,...,f_m$.

Comment: You mean than then you can choose the numerator to be equal to the denominator right? Do you think a solution can be found when the $f_0$ is not a convex combination of the other pdfs? Another example such that a solution can be found is when $f_1 = \dots = f_M$ but I am trying to consider the more general setting.

Comment: I give an answer below that considers the case when $f_0$ is uniformly distributed over an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some cases:

#### Case 1:  Suppose $f_0 \in Conv(f_1, ..., f_m)$.

Suppose  $f_0(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i f_i(x)$ for some nonnegative constants $\beta_i$ that sum to 1. Then we can choose $\alpha_i=\beta_i$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$ and we obtain the desired equalities: 
$$ \int f_k(x)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i f_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx = 0  \quad \forall k \in \{1, ..., m\} $$

#### Case 2: $f_0$ is uniform over $[a,b]$

Suppose the PDFs all have support over an interval $[a,b]$ and that $f_0$ is uniform over this interval. If $f_0 \notin Conv(f_1, ..., f_m)$, a natural choice is to "project" $f_0$ into $Conv(f_1, ..., f_m)$ (in a KL sense):

Let $P = \{(p_1, ..., p_m): p_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^mp_i=1\}$ denote the probability simplex. Find probabilities $(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m) \in P$ that minimize the following expression: 
$$ g(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)=\int_a^b \left(\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_if_i(x)  \right)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i f_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx$$
Suppose we are lucky enough to find a minimizer $\alpha^*=(\alpha_1^*, \ldots, \alpha_n^*)$ that has strictly positive entries, so that $\alpha_i^*>0$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ (so it is not a boundary point of $P$).  It follows by property of minimizers that there is a constant $c$ such that: 
$$ \left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial \alpha_k}\right|_{\alpha^*} = c \quad \forall k \in \{1, ..., m\}$$
(Otherwise, if the partial with respect to $i$ is larger than the partial with respect to $j$, we can improve $g$ by taking a small amount $\delta$ from $\alpha_i$ and giving it to $\alpha_j$, which contradicts the fact that we are already at a minimum.)
In particular for all $k \in \{1, ..., m\}$ we have
\begin{align}
c &=  \int_a^b f_k(x)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_if_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx + \int_a^b f_k(x)f_0(x)dx\\
&= \int_a^b f_k(x)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_if_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx + \frac{1}{b-a} 
\end{align}
and so the desired integrals are the same for all $k \in \{1, ..., m\}$.

#### General case

Let $f_0, f_1, ..., f_m$ be general. Define:
$$ v_k = \int f_k(x)f_0(x)dx \quad \forall k \in \{1, ..., m\} $$
Define the function $h:[0,1]^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ h(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m) = -\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_iv_i + \int \left(\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i f_i(x)\right)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_if_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx $$
Now minimize $h(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)$ over $(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)\in P$.  Again suppose the minimizer $(\alpha_1^*, ..., \alpha_m^*)$ has  $\alpha_i^*>0$ for all $i\in \{1, ..., m\}$.  Then again we must have a constant $c$ such that 
$$ \left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial \alpha_k}\right|_{\alpha^*} = c \quad \forall k \in \{1, ..., m\}$$
Thus for all $k \in \{1, ..., m\}$ we get: 
\begin{align}
c &=  -v_k +  \int  f_k(x)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_if_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx + \int  f_k(x)f_0(x)dx\\
&= \int f_k(x)\log\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_if_i(x)}{f_0(x)}\right)dx 
\end{align}
and so the desired integrals are the same for all $k \in \{1, ..., m\}$.

---

Fortunately, the functions $g(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)$ and $h(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)$ are always convex functions!  So the minimization is always a convex minimization.

In fact, convexity implies that there exist strictly positive values $\alpha_i$ that sum to 1 that satisfy the desired equalities if and only if there is a  minimizer of the function $h$ over the simplex $P$ that is not a boundary point of $P$.

Comment: The same argument as the uniform case holds whenever $\int f_i(x)f_0(x)dx$ is the same for all $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$.

Comment: Could you explain at which point is the derivative evaluated at to be equal to $c$? I am not entirely clear on this argument. I am guessing not at $\alpha^*$ since there it should be zero. Thank you for your time!

Comment: It is at $\alpha^*$. For intuition, try minimizing $g(x,y)=2x^2+y^2$ over $(x,y)\in \{x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x+y=1\}$.  You will find $(x^*,y^*)$ is not a boundary point and so $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*) = \frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: Following this momentum, I was able to get a more general solution than I expected (i.e., general $f_0$).  So this result above turns out to be kind of nice.  What is the context of this problem? It would be interesting if we could use it for something.  Of course, it remains to consider what happens if the minimizer is on the boundary...

Comment: It has to do with a hypothesis testing problem in mixture models. I am trying to understand how log-likelihood ratio tests would perform when the distributions are not matched, e.g. how the false alarm and probabilities of detection are affected. Thank you for the valuable input!